# Running apache in an ubuntu Docker container on a RedHat machine

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, redhat, rhel

I am new to Docker and have been trying to configure a standard default install of Apache2 running on the [ubuntu:14.04](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) image.

This seems to work just fine when the Docker host machine is running Ubuntu, but when I try to run this same config on a machine running RHEL 6, I get apache config errors having to do with file permissions. Specifically, the default apache page returns a 403 forbidden page.

I thought the point of Docker was that I could create a container on one environment and it should behave exactly the same on any other environment.. am I way off?

Comment: Might be SELinux. See whether the problem persists when you disable SELinux enforcement with `setenforce 0`. If so, re-enable enforcement and add the `http_sys_content_t` label to the files that Apache needs access to.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but it may be that you need RHEL 7.  From here you can:

docker pull rhscl/httpd-24-rhel7

See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1378023